# Old passport with Active Visa

Tags: passports, international-travel, passport-renewals

I am planning to change my passport from my Maiden name to my husband's Surname. My concern is that my active visa from maiden name will be cancelled. Specifically my visas for Germany and Canada. Or they will still allow me to use the old passport since it's still valid up to the next year?

Answer (score 2):

You can continue to use the old passport with a valid visa alongside your new passport.

[Can I travel to Canada with valid visa on old/expired passport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/87429/can-i-travel-to-canada-with-valid-visa-on-old-expired-passport)

[Are there any rule changes to using a Schengen visa in an expired passport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/94695/are-there-any-rule-changes-to-using-a-schengen-visa-in-an-expired-passport?r=SearchResults)