# Passport thread coming off from the bottom end

Tags: schengen-visas, india, damaged-passports

I have got the visa stamped for Schengen countries. But i noticed i have a small binding coming off from the bottom end of the passport. I have attached a pic, please refer the same. Do i need to get it reissued ?
Also, if I have the visa in old passport, then do i need to apply again for the same visa on reissued passport ?

[image]

Comment: For a definition of a damaged passport, see the link to the Indian Ministry of External Affairs [in this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/39263/indian-passport-first-page-ripped-is-this-considered-damaged)

Comment: Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/94695/are-there-any-rule-changes-to-using-a-schengen-visa-in-an-expired-passport